# Java vs Python for elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

We are starting with Elastic search for a full text search and still not started anything with code level. We are familiar with both Java and Python as well. Some one could suggest, which one is preferable to use for building a ES application - Java or Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language is not an issue here I think. Especially when you are considering Java or Python. Both have official [clients](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html) and if something is not implemented there you can always communicate with Elasticsearch directly via REST. Elasticsearch is written in Java so the Java clients could me often faster up-to-date but it is not a rule.